# In Epsilon-Delta proof, why is $3x^2|y|/(x^2 + y^2) \Leftarrow 3|y| = 3\sqrt{y^2} \Leftarrow 3\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exponentiation, absolute-value

This is part of a Epsilon-Delta proof to show that: $$\lim_{(x, y) \to 0}\frac{3x^2y}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$$ The proof began with: $$\frac {3x^2|y|}{(x^2 + y^2)} < \epsilon$$ It was then pointed out that $x^2 \Leftarrow x^2 + y^2 \because y^2 >= 0$, which I understood.

In that way, I get why: $$\frac {3x^2|y|}{(x^2 + y^2)} \le 3|y|$$ But I don't understand how they can say it is equal to: $$ 3\sqrt{y^2} \le 3\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $$

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty heavily. Please check to ensure that I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: Note 2:  It is clearly not generally true that $3\,|y|≤ \frac 3{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$.  Just take $y=2$, $x=0$.  Perhaps you left off some assumptions?

Comment: I think it should be $3|y| = 3\sqrt {y^2}$ by definition, and $3\sqrt {y^2} \le 3\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ as $x^2 \ge 0$ and the square root function is montonicly increasing so $\frac {3x^2|y|}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}} \le 3|y| \le 3\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$

Comment: This appears to be lacking context.  The question seems to be part of some broader discussion. Perhaps in that context we are told that $y$ is near $0$?  In any case, the statement is false as given.

Comment: @lulu I think in your editing, you have changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @DougM  That is sadly possible.  What specifically did I change?

Comment: The header, which is the only place the actual question appears, is very hard to read.  I think the OP should clarify the intent.

Comment: @lulu I rolled it back and cleaned it up.  You had it go from $\frac {3x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} < 3|y|$ to  $\frac {3}{|y|} \le \frac {3}{\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}}$  The OP asked an early question on the limit as $(x,y) \to 0$ of a very similar function in a different post.

Comment: @DougM  Ok...but then I don't understand the question.  What does it mean to say that one inequality equals another?  Both of the current inequalities hold generally...is that all that is meant?

Comment: @lulu Show via $\epsilon - \delta$ that $\lim_\limits{(x,y) \to 0} \frac {3x^2y}{x^2 + y^2} = 0$.  Then by the algebra above $|f(x,y)| < 3\delta$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. First, you can start saying that $x^{2}\geq 0$, then adding $y^{2}$ in both sides of the inequality you get:
$$ x^{2}+y^{2}\geq y^{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq\sqrt{y^{2}}$$
because $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$ is monotone increasing on its domain. Now use that $g(t)=3t$ is also monotone increasing and then you have:
$$3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq 3\sqrt{y^{2}}=3\vert{y}\vert,$$
this means
$$3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq 3\vert{y}\vert,$$
as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ you can suppose that $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$,  so  $$x^{2}+y^{2}\neq 0$$ and you can write:
$$3\vert{y}\vert\leq 3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<3\delta.$$

Second, you can say that $y^{2}\geq 0$ then adding in both sides $x^{2}$ you get:
$$ y^{2}+x^{2}\geq x^{2} $$
we know that  $x^{2}+y^{2}>0$ then you can divide by $x^{2}+y^{2}$ and get:
$$ 1\geq \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}},$$
Now you can multiply both sides off the last inequality by $\vert{y}\vert\geq 0$:
$$ \vert{y}\vert\geq \frac{x^{2}\vert{y}\vert}{x^{2}+y^{2}} $$
Multiply by 3 both sides to get:
$$ \frac{3x^{2}\vert{y}\vert}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 3\vert{y}\vert<3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<3\delta.$$
You can put $\delta(\epsilon)=\displaystyle{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$. Notice that you always have:
$$y^{2}\geq 0 \Rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2} \geq x^{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq\vert{x}\vert$$
in the same way
$$x^{2}\geq 0 \Rightarrow x^{2}+y^{2} \geq y^{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\geq\vert{y}\vert$$

From the inequality $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq x^{2}$ you can directly multiply both sides by $3\vert{y}\vert$ to have: 
$$\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{3\vert{y}\vert x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 3\vert{y}\vert$$

Comment: I would say that $3\sqrt{x^{2}}\leq 3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle{\frac{3\vert{y}\vert x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 3\vert{y}\vert}$ instead of $3\sqrt{y^{2}}\leq 3\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$. But not equal.